# Get the Substring of a List in C#

Tags: c#, string, linq

I am about to get the substring of a list. Here is my LINQ. (Read the XML from a third-party service.)

```
 var Payment = from Main in xml.Descendants(ns + "OTA_AirBookRQ")
               select new
               {
                   DepartureDate = Main
                                   .Elements(ns+"Segment")
                                   .Elements(ns+"DepartureDate")
                                   .ToList(),
               }
```

`Payment.DepartureDate[0].Value` returns a date as `"2012-11-14T19:05:00"`. All I need to get from this is `"19:05:00"` . How do I achieve this?

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: @Oded Thanks for your replay. I tried like foreach(var a in Payment){a.DepatureDatetime.Findlastindex("T");}

Comment: @Oded If it is a string it possible, string polo = "Chennai(Madras)";
        int index=polo.LastIndexOf("(");
        string mas = polo.Substring(0, index); But i dont know with List

Comment: Your question is not quite clear: What does it mean to _"get a substring of a list"_? Should your final result be a single time value, or another list? I.e. do you need to extract the time component for each `Payment.DepartureDate[n].Value`, or only for the first element?

Comment: @stakx My final result should be"19:05:00".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DateTime.Parse("2012-11-14T19:05:00").ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.,I tried  DateTime.Parse(chk.DepartureDateTime[0].Value).ToString("HH:mm:ss"); It is working excellent., thanks again

Comment: My guess `((DateTime)chk.DepartureDateTime[0]).ToString("HH:mm:ss")` should also work

Answer (score 0):

It makes more sense to do this with the `DateTime.Parse(dateString)` method, but if you must use substrings, simply go:  `string.substring(firstPos, length);` (in your case - assuming your date string is named strDate:  `strDate.substring(9, strDate.length-1);`

Substrings:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.100).aspx

Date Time parsing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx

Comment: Thanks i will check with it.